# Sending message with special chars to pubnub server throw php sdk

Tags: php, escaping, pubnub

**The problem:** When I send message from php to pubnub:

```
$msg = array("author"=>"MisterX","text"=>"Who's here?"); 
$pubnub = new Pubnub(PubNubPublishKey,PubNubSubscribeKey,PubNubSecretKey);
$publish_result = $pubnub->publish('chat1',$msg);
```

Clients (on JS SDK) get this message like:

> MisterX: Who\'s here?

But when client send the same messages from JS it's works normal:

> MisterX: Who's here?

Is it bug in PubNub PHP SDK? Maybe I need to make additional manipulation with `$msg` before put in to `publish()`, but there is no mention in docs.

Answer (score 0):

Test this

```
$msg = array("author"=>"MisterX","text"=>"Who's here?"); 
$pubnub = new Pubnub(PubNubPublishKey,PubNubSubscribeKey,PubNubSecretKey);
$publish_result = $pubnub->publish('chat1',$msg);
```

Comment: I have the same code on the real app. **"** for **text** key is missing only on StackOverflow. (Fixed now)